# Why was the NAA flag declined on this answer?

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, specific-answer, not-an-answer

I got twice a declined flag for [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52995926/5468463), but I still stubbornly think that the post is a link-only answer and should be deleted.
The mods told me to downvote instead. But I am probably greedy too.

In my comprehension many criteria are reunited for the post to be deleted:

- The question doesn't ask for a recommendation package;
- The answer doesn't help to know how to use the package; no guidance is provided;
- The link is not referring to a specific documentation on the language or the framework, etc.
- The package is deprecated;
- Maybe too subjective -  the username and the lack of activity of the user since the post suggest possible spam;

Can someone explain me what is the use of this answer and why it is not a link-only?

Comment: I think the author of that answer is very well aware of what makes an answer link-only, so in their mission to do as little effort as possible they added a reference to a function call to it. If you now strip away the link, the answer becomes *"You can useclickOutside() method from ng-click-outside package"*. That IS an answer. Not one I would be proud of.

Comment: @Gimby, Where did you take that idea that they knew?

Comment: This is a first time that a I see this kind of package recommending post not be deleted. All my flags were accepted previously. It should have been at least tranferred to a comment. It cannot stand as an answer

Comment: From assumption making. It is well-crafted laziness.

Comment: I think you are right about this being a very low-effort answer, not one that anyone should be proud of, @Gimby, but I really don't see the evidence for (and don't agree with) the assertion that the user who posted it knew exactly what they were doing. It was a brand-new user. There's no reason to suppose they were familiar with Stack Overflow's expectations and deliberately skirting them. That just isn't reasonable, and it isn't consistent with our general presumption of good faith. To me, it's clear that the author of the answer was *trying* to be helpful and provide a relevant solution.

Comment: *"This is a first time that a I see this kind of package recommending post not be deleted."* This is horrifying. What this says to me is that there are a *ton* of reviewers out there who are reviewing incorrectly, and that we are systematically destroying answers that add value to this site. If that's the case, it's really great that we were able to have this discussion, and that you and others who read Meta can learn what types of answers should not be deleted. I suppose the already-overworked moderator team will have to work harder in handing out suspensions for incorrect reviews.

Comment: @CodyGray, a very quick search showed me those flags were helpful. Are the posts similar? https://stackoverflow.com/a/70999048/5468463, https://stackoverflow.com/a/45967835/5468463,https://stackoverflow.com/a/34590504/5468463, https://stackoverflow.com/a/56230401/5468463

Comment: @Vega The difference is that those 4 answers *only* mention the name of a library/tool/package, which I believe counts as NAA. The answer you're referring to in this meta question also mentions a function from the library that can be used, which makes it an answer. It does look like Cody's answer suggests that the name of the library is sufficient, however that has not been my experience of how mods handle NAA flags on such answers (i.e. mods seem willing to delete them, as in the 4 example answers linked in your comment).

Answer (score 16):

The question asks how to do a specific thing. The answer recommends a package with a name sounding *unmistakably* like it will achieve what the asker is trying to do.

Is the answer great? No. Should it have more explanation and details added, ideally even sample code? Yeah, definitely. Are these shortcomings reason enough to downvote it? Yeah, that's why I suggested doing so. :-) But an answer being imperfect or not great is not sufficient grounds for it to be unilaterally deleted by a moderator.

There's no evidence that is spam. You did mention the theory, and I did check. I can't find any evidence it's spam, or even anything that smelled funny to me. Considering the account hasn't posted anything *since* that answer, that's not the type of behavior I would typically associate with a spammer. I also can't find any evidence that the answer is irrelevant or inapplicable to the question, which would be another hallmark of spam.

It seems like a good-faith answer that someone might find helpful. We don't have a rule against answers that suggest using a library/tool/package to solve a problem. We don't delete answers because the suggestion they gave later becomes deprecated. I'm not a subject-matter expert here, but I claim that doesn't matter. Moderators aren't expected to be subject-matter experts. Even if you could prove the answer was wrong/bad, that wouldn't be sufficient grounds for a moderator to delete it.

While reading this Meta question, I re-assessed the decision again, and I still came up with the same conclusion as I did when I declined the flag, and as the other moderator who declined the original NAA flag did. I even clicked through to the linked page, found [this demo of the package](https://echeung.me/ng-click-outside/), and confirmed that it does, in fact, work to detect when one clicks outside of a particular region. Which is exactly what the asker is trying to do. There's enough information in that post to help someone. Deleting it seems like it would be doing harm, not improving the site.

I really don't know what more explanation I can provide. This seems like [a very clear-cut case of an imperfect answer that could justifiably be downvoted (or, better yet, edited and improved), but not one that can be justifiably flagged as "not an answer" or deleted by a moderator](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265552/when-to-flag-an-answer-as-not-an-answer). It's fine to flag something because it smells funny ("might be spam"), but one really needs more reason than that to delete answers that appear, at least superficially, to be relevant to the question and good-faith attempts to answer the question.

Comment: Ok for the not spam and being a bad answer worthy to downvote. But why it is not a link-only answer? There is no context and how to use it. What is creation for a such a post?

Comment: It's not a link-only answer. [The FAQ explains why](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265553). It recommends a specific package to use. That's an answer.  The FAQ even gives the specific example of an answer "where the link text is a function/API and the link target is the associated documentation" as *not* being a "link-only answer". A link-only answer is one where there is no answer. This has an answer.

Comment: The link to a package is not documentation! If it was a link to Array.reverse(), for example, then it could be comprehensible, but that package is a third party library and in no way a reference

Comment: [We keep having this same discussion about what is and is not a "link-only answer".](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370) It seems clear to me. I don't know how to make it any more clear. How is linking to the official page for the package any different from linking to documentation? The answer tells you the name of the package you should use. Even if the link weren't there, it'd still contain the name of the package that could be used to solve the exact problem being asked about. Again, not the world's greatest answer, and in need of improvement, but we don't delete answers for those reasons.

Comment: @Vega Even if the link is unreachable, the name of the package is part of it. It would be slightly clearer if it said "use <package name> URL: https://www.npmjs.com/package/<package name>" but the package can still be discerned without this clarification. The alternative to avoid the link is to just list the package name without "https://www.npmjs.com/package/" in front of it. If *that* transformation makes it not link-only then the URL was never really the only information in the answer.

Comment: @Vega It's always been my understanding that the defining feature of a link only answer is that if the text wasn't actually a hyperlink, it would contain no information; all of the relevant information is in the link **target**. (The rationale being that the link may die in future, and the text with no link is effectively what would be left) Your criteria that the answer suggests using a particular method without providing any further explanation suggests that it's a poor answer, not that it's a link-only answer.

Answer (score 10):

> I still stubbornly think that the post is a link-only answer and should be deleted.

Link-only answers (outside of spam) are when the link is relied upon to *explain* the answer. Without the link, there is no information in such an answer.

In the current case, the link isn't there to say how to solve the problem with the package; it *provides* the package. The post says what function to call. This is low quality, but it isn't link-only.

Comment: Don't we delete low quality posts?

Comment: @Vega no we delete VERY low quality posts. Low quality posts we downvote.

Comment: More specifically, we delete posts that are incoherent and/or are not even an attempt to answer the question that was asked. We do *not* delete answers that are low-quality or answers that are wrong. We never have. Our policies surrounding this have been *remarkably* consistent going back for a decade on Stack Overflow. It is exceptionally concerning to me that at least one active reviewer is unaware of these policies, and, more importantly, that they have been reviewing this way for years, managing to get valid answers removed from the site and developing such egregious misunderstandings.

Comment: (I think that policy is *bad*, though.)